# Strategies to protect files inside the "uploads" folder in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am creating custom giftcard PDF's on a client's site and want to protect them from public access while still being able accessing in the backend. Blocking a specific directory via Apache's .htaccess or nginx' location block rules works fine but now how can I access the files in the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Strategy #1

### Use cryptic folder and file names

In this case you don't need to block the access to the PDF's via Nginx or Apache (except traversing the directories, but this should be turned on anyway). The path to the PDF's could look like this for example:

`/wp-content/uploads/plugin-name/year-month-day/ndLr83nH06Vd63jnbm46Ghied7/giftcard-order-0815-item-8015.pdf`

```
public function generatePDF(){
        (....) 
        $upload_dir = ABSPATH . "wp-content/uploads/plugin-name/" . date( "Y-m-d" ) . "/" . $this->randomString(24);
        if ( ! file_exists( $upload_dir ) ) {
            mkdir( $upload_dir, 0775, true );
        }
        $path = $upload_dir . "/giftcard-order-$order_id-item-$item_id.pdf";
        //mpdf is the library I am using to generate custom PDF's
        $mpdf->Output( $path, \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE );

        return $path;
}

public function randomString( $length = 4 ) {
    $characters       = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen( $characters );
    $randomString     = '';
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++ ) {
        $randomString .= $characters[ rand( 0, $charactersLength - 1 ) ];
    }

    return $randomString;
}
```

You can then simply use the path generated by the generatePDF() method to create an attachment for the giftcard post (post_type = shop_coupon in WooCommerce) and then access it through the media library.

```
public function attachPDF( $pdf_path, $shop_coupon_id, $order_id ) {


    $attachment = array(
        'post_title'  => "Giftcard PDF - Order #$order_id, Coupon #$shop_coupon_id",
        'post_status' => 'private',
        'post_parent' => $shop_coupon_id
    );
    $attach_id  = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $pdf_path );

    return $attach_id;

}
```

Now you only need to setup fail2ban on the server to protect your site from brute force attacks. Or you can use one of the WordPress security plugins (WordFence, WP Cerber etc).

## Strategy #2

### Deny access to files via Nginx/Apache rules

This strategy makes it very simple to block any unauthorized access to the files you want to protect. On the other hand it's now more difficult to program functions for accessing the files when needed. With this strategy you now can only access the files via PHP code. So if you want to open or download the files you will have to write custom frontend applications for this or use external plugins which offer such functionality.